# Xbox 360S setup fails as Media Extender for Windows 7 laptop using E2500 Linksys router

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, xbox360, media-center-extender

I have a Linksys E2500 router, an Xbox 360S, and a Toshiba Laptop with Windows 7.  When I try to use the Xbox as a media extender for the laptop, it fails when I go through the router with the following error:

[image]

When I connect the laptop directly to the Xbox, they can find each other fine and I can stream video, but obviously this is not the solution, just a troubleshooting step.

I've tried various things suggested for Linksys routers: disabling UPnP, unchecking Filter Anonymous Internet Requests, but it doesn't seem to work.  To make matters even more fun it seems the E2500 is new enough there's not a lot specifically out there.  There is plenty for older Linksys routers but the suggestions don't seem to solve my problems.

Is there anyone out there with an E2500 who knows the proper settings to get my laptop to recognize my 360 as an extender, or has some good guesses?

Do the static IP and port forwarding suggestions have an effect on this?  Or it's just for online game play?

**UPDATE**: I've noticed that it WILL find the extender if the laptop uses a physical connection to the E2500 router, but it can NOT find it if the laptop is connecting wirelessly.

Comment: The computer and the computer are in the same network when connected to the router (I don't know the E2500, that's why I'm asking)?

Comment: The computer is going wirelessly into the LinkSys E2500 router, and the XBox is coming in to a physical port on the backside of the E2500 router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I read your `Update` section, I was going to suggest you do exactly that!

I would check through your wireless settings on the router to see if you have any options such as "Wireless Isolation", "Wireless Separation" or similar sounding settings as it seems to me that based on you not having issues with wired, your wireless network is being separated from your wired network.

This is a good set up for mixed security environments (Think of small hotels that have one router and want to offer wifi alongside their own network), but can cause havoc for home networks such as your own!

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I can't check it till I get home tonight, but will do so and let you know (and of course mark your answer if works or let you know what happened if not).

Comment: not seeing a "Wireless Isolation" or "Separation" settings, could it be called something else?

Comment: There are loads of things it could be.... Can you post a screenshot of the Wireless, Wireless Security, Security and any other tabs and I will try to help you further (mask/blur keys/sensitive stuff).

Comment: Okay, will do tonight.  I have a speaker's dinner at a local tech conference, but after that I can post 'em.